# Почему Git оставляет старые названия папок после их переименований?

Tags: git

Ситуация такая, есть ветка `dev` и вот такая структура проекта

```
MyProj/Foo/MyFile.java
```

Я делаю из нее другую ветку `dev` -> `dev_test_first` и добавляю в эту директорию еще несколько файлов

```
MyProj/Foo/MyFile.java
MyProj/Foo/MyFile2.java
MyProj/Foo/MyFile3.java
```

Делаю `commit` тут же.

Теперь делаем еще одну ветку из `dev` -> `dev_test_second` меняю название папки, удаляю `MyFile.java` и добавляю еще файл `MyFile4`

Получилось вот так

```
MyProj/Boo/MyFile.java <- !! DELETED !! 

MyProj/Boo/MyFile4.java
```

Делаю `commit` и `merge` с `dev` веткой и `push` в `origin`.

Теперь из ветки `dev_test_first` делаю `pull origin dev`

и я ожидаю, что структура моего проекта будет иметь во первых переименованую дерикторию, а во вторых я получу дополнительный файл `MyFile4` который был создан на ветке `dev_test_second`

ОЖИДАНИЕ

```
MyProj/Boo/MyFile.java
MyProj/Boo/MyFile2.java
MyProj/Boo/MyFile3.java 
MyProj/Boo/MyFile4.java
```

но вместо этого получается вот так

РЕАЛЬНОСТЬ

```
MyProj/Foo/MyFile.java
MyProj/Foo/MyFile2.java
MyProj/Foo/MyFile3.java 
MyProj/Boo/MyFile4.java
```

Почему так получается?

**Правка**

При чем если посмотреть на такую ситуацию, допустим в ветке `dev_test_second` мы не будем добавлять никакие файлы, а просто переименуем папку и все. То когда будем сливать эти ветки, то мы получим просто переименованую директорию. Но почему тогда когда мы переименовываем и + добавляем дополнительные файлы, то гит как бы создает новую дирикторию?

Comment: возможно, вы для переименования использовали не `git mv`, а `git rm + git add`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin одно из достоинств гита (а также его и недостаток) - в том, что команда `git mv` полностью эквивалентна `git rm + git add`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, мой личный опыт подсказывает: авто-детектирование переименования, т.е. без явного `git mv`, происходит не всегда.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я для переименования не использовал никаких команд, просто переименовал дирикторию потом сделал `git add .` и `git commit`. Я добавил пару строк в впрос

Comment: @PavelMayorov я для переименования не использовал никаких команд, просто переименовал дирикторию потом сделал `git add .` и `git commit`. Я добавил пару строк в впрос

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin оно и после `git mv` точно так же происходит не всегда

Answer (score 1):

Так получается по той причине, что git в принципе не отслеживает папки, он следит только за файлами.

А ещё git не отслеживает переименования.

То есть второй коммит с точки зрения git выглядит вот так:

```
удален MyProj/Foo/MyFile.java
создан MyProj/Boo/MyFile.java
создан MyProj/Boo/MyFile4.java
```

Соответственно, когда вы сливаете этот коммит с первым, то все файлы сливаются независимо. Файл `MyProj/Foo/MyFile.java` при этом оказывается в состоянии конфликта (изменён+удалён).

Comment: Отслеживает или нет не знаю, но если файл переименовать, то гит это понимает и пишет *foo.bar renamed to bar.foo*.

Comment: @Эникейщик это просто визуализация, притом эвристическая (т.е. он может и не понять что файл-то один и тот же, если его достаточно сильно изменить в том же коммите)

Comment: Я не уверен, что у меня правильно получилось задать вопрос, поэтому я добавил еще несколько строк в вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста